# DateTime class common error displayed again

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight

I run into a little common problem with datetime class that I have no idea how to resolve.

I don't know what the error is but I see the troubleshooting tips are displayed as

> When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object. Make sure your method arguments are in the right format.

Here is the piece of code I extract from my program,

```
public IEnumerable<CONTACT_INFO> GetContactInfo(string tableName)
{
    DataTable dt = GetUserInfo(tableName);
    List<CONTACT_INFO> lst = new List<CONTACT_INFO>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {              
        string sDate = "";
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["birthday"].ToString()))
        {
            sDate = row["birthday"].ToString();
        }
        string format = "yyyyMMdd";

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider =CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sDate))
        {
            datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, format, provider).ToShortDateString();
        }

        if (row["companyname"].ToString().CompareTo("companylogo") != 0)
        {
            string profile_time = row["profile_timestamp"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile_time))
            {
                CSTimeZone time = new CSTimeZone();
                profile_time = time.FromUnix(Convert.ToDouble(profile_time)).ToShortDateString()+" "+
                                 time.FromUnix(Convert.ToDouble(profile_time)).ToLongTimeString();
             }

             string lastUseNetTime = row["last_used_networktime"].ToString();
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastUseNetTime))
             {

                 CSTimeZone time = new CSTimeZone();
                 double sec = Convert.ToDouble(lastUseNetTime) * 60;
                 lastUseNetTime = time.FromUnix(Convert.ToDouble(sec)).ToShortDateString() + " " +
                        time.FromUnix(Convert.ToDouble(sec)).ToLongTimeString();
             }
             string lastOnlineTime = row["lastonline_timestamp"].ToString();
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastOnlineTime))
             {
                 CSTimeZone time = new CSTimeZone();
                 lastOnlineTime = time.FromUnix(Convert.ToDouble(lastOnlineTime)).ToShortDateString() + " " +
                        time.FromUnix(Convert.ToDouble(lastOnlineTime)).ToLongTimeString();
             }
             lst.Add(new CONTACT_INFO()
             {
                 gender=Convert.ToInt32(row["gender"].ToString()),
                 timezone=row["timezone"].ToString(),                        
                 fullName = row["fullname"].ToString(),
                 profile_timestamp = profile_time,
                 last_used_networktime = lastUseNetTime,
                 lastonline_timestamp = lastOnlineTime,
                 birthday = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sDate) ? "" : datetime
             });
         }
     }
     return lst;
 }
```

The function FromUnix is written as

```
public DateTime FromUnix(double seconds)
{
    DateTime datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
    return datetime.AddSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you know what the error is?  What is going wrong?

Comment: 'Troubleshooting tips'?  What are these, where do they come from?  When you run the program, where does it occur?  This seems to be a `FormatException`.  Which is causing it?  Have you debugged the code?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is a parsing problem
The following line would throw exceptions if the value of sDate is not in the defined format of yyyyMMdd

```
datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, format, provider).ToShortDateString();
```

I would first use TryParseExact instead of a simple Parse since you do not seem to be using try/catch clauses. It might be a good idea to use the debugger to see exactly where your program is failing.

Other example of potential failures in your code are

```
double sec = Convert.ToDouble(lastUseNetTime) * 60;
```

Use double.tryParse

```
Convert.ToInt32(row["gender"].ToString()
```

If gender turns out not to be a number another exception will be thrown

etc...

Comment: I'm curious about that *60 as well, and would like to see the workings for obtaining this magic number. :)